# Delay when pressing Command-Shift-4

Tags: screen-capture

The better way to take a screenshot is Command-Shift-4.

But since switching to Big Sur on an M1 Mac, I am seeing that this key combination produces a delay before seeing the crosshairs.

When a computer doesn't do what I ask right away, I do the same thing again and press harder. So how do I prevent this delay and reduce RSI?

Comment: What kind of Mac is it (Mini or Macbook)? If you switch to another user account (or create a new one for testing), does it have the same delay?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the Screenshot app, and in the Screen Recording options, select "None", for the audio input.

I have no idea why, but this will fix the delay before the crosshair appears for Cmd+Shift+4 screenshots.

Comment: Presumably the delay is due to the time it takes to initialize the chosen audio device? Great catch though, this also worked for me.

Comment: This is logically insane but does work, in the sense that taking a screen shot can be delayed by screen recording staff.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a possible hardware issue with the keyboard. You may have to bring it into an Apple store for diagnosis.

But if you really want to know for sure you could do a [re-install](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) or [clean install](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/clean-install-macos-3637409/) of the Mac OS which would rule out any software problems.

If you want to try something less drastic, [create a new user](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-other-users-on-your-mac-mtusr001/mac) and log in as that user and see if you can replicate the issue.